# How to launch program in floating with certain key bindings in i3?

Tags: manjaro, i3-window-manager

I'm on Manjaro with i3. I'm trying to make certain key bindings launch stuff in floating, while others don't. I've tried several things so far:

## 1. Straight up `floating toggle` with `bindsym`

```
# in i3/config
bindsym $mod+p          exec $term -e python
bindsym $mod+Shift+p            exec $term -e python; floating toggle
```

Unfortunately, this launches Python in normal (split/tabbed/stacking) mode and whatever I was focused on before launching Python.

## 2. Put every Python launched by `bindsym` in floating

```
# in i3/config
for_window [title="python"] floating toggle
bindsym $mod+p          exec $term -e python
```

This actually works to automatically launch Python in floating mode! However, *any and every* Python window launched with `bindsym` in floating mode...

## 3. Custom window title

```
# in i3/config
for_window [title="[.*]_floating"] floating toggle
bindsym $mod+p          exec --title "python_floating" $term -e python
```

Unfortunately, `exec` doesn't seem to have the `--title` flag so the `bindsym` doesn't work at all.

I've tried reading the [documentation](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html) and `man i3` but haven't found anything that helps so far. This doesn't seem to have been solved. The 3 similar posts I've found googling [[1]](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/4730/launch-program-floating.1.html) [[2]](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/40jqad/how_can_i_exec_as_a_floating_window/) [[3]](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/4550/launch-in-floating-mode/index.html) look like my solution #2;

Given my suggested solutions which haven't totally solved this problem, how can I launch stuff where only certain `bindsym`s launch in floating mode?

Answer (score 0):

Your third option was very close.  As mentioned in the i3 FAQ [here](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/5866/two-keybindings-for-starting-terminal-normally-and-floating/) with both [urxvt](https://linux.die.net/man/1/urxvt) and [xterm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm) you can use the `-name` parameter. You can then define whether it is floating based on *instance*.

For example your floating/not floating python could be done like this:

```
set $term urxvt

# floating python
for_window  [class="URxvt" instance="floating"] floating toggle resize set 1500 1000, move position 100 200
bindsym $mod+Shift+P exec $term -name 'floating' -e python

# not floating
bindsym $mod+Shift+O exec $term -name 'not' -e python
```